# edittext value changes position while scrolling in custom listview in android

Tags: android

I have created a custom list view with 6 colomns. Each row is populated.
the first 3 fields are textviews,which are filled from db. Then a spinner and the last two edittexts.
i want to enter values to edittexts and spinner.. this much is ok.
The problem is when i enter values in edittext and after that if i scroll the list, the values entered in edittext changes in position. if i entered in first row, after scrolling it will be in last row or any other.. how i can solve this.. Need help pls..
My adapter class is given below.

```
public class CustomTransAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public ArrayList<retrieveTrans> ret_arrArrayList;
private List<retrieveTrans> ret_translist;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterspin;
String time, currntdate, status;
String Maxcramnt, balamount;
double Mamount, Bamount, actualamnt;
String idpref, str_agent_id2, accno;
int trcheck;
int d = 0;
String tramnt = "", remarks = "";
Context context;

int count;

public CustomTransAdapter(NewTransactionSheet newTransactionSheet,
        int transListPop, List<retrieveTrans> translist) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super();
    this.ret_translist = translist;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(newTransactionSheet);
    this.ret_arrArrayList = new ArrayList<retrieveTrans>();
    this.ret_arrArrayList.addAll(translist);
    this.context = newTransactionSheet;

    String[] items = new String[] { "Type", "credit", "debit" };
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapterspin = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            newTransactionSheet, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            items);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ret_translist.size();
}

   @Override
 public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ret_translist.get(arg0);
 }

 @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
  }

  class ViewHolder {
    TextView acc_txt, name_txt, balAmnt_txt;
    Spinner trans_spinner;
    EditText transAmnt_edittxt, remarks_edittxt;
    Button save;

   }

  @Override
   public View getView(final int pos, View cv, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        View row = cv;

        int p = pos;
        Log.e("position of getview:", "" + p);
        if (cv == null) {

            cv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trans_pop_list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.acc_txt = (TextView) cv
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtTransAccNo_pop);
            holder.name_txt = (TextView) cv
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtTransName_pop);
            holder.balAmnt_txt = (TextView) cv
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtTransBalAmnt_pop);

            holder.trans_spinner = (Spinner) cv
                    .findViewById(R.id.spinTrans_Type);

            holder.transAmnt_edittxt = (EditText) cv
                    .findViewById(R.id.editTransAmnt_pop);
            holder.save = (Button) cv.findViewById(R.id.save);

            holder.remarks_edittxt = (EditText) cv
                    .findViewById(R.id.editRemarks_pop);
            cv.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) cv.getTag();
        }

        holder.acc_txt.setText("" + ret_translist.get(pos).getRetAccNo());
        String hari = holder.acc_txt.getText().toString();
        holder.name_txt.setText("" + ret_translist.get(pos).getRetName());
        holder.balAmnt_txt.setText(""
                + ret_translist.get(pos).getRetBalAmnt());

        String[] items = new String[] { "Type", "credit", "debit" };
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapterspin = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);

        final String haris = holder.name_txt.getText().toString();          

        holder.trans_spinner.setAdapter(adapterspin);

        /* ******************* Save button Click **************** */

        holder.save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                int position = pos;

                final String accno = holder.acc_txt.getText().toString();

                final String tramnt = holder.transAmnt_edittxt.getText()
                        .toString();
                String remarks = holder.remarks_edittxt.getText()
                        .toString();
                final String spinner = holder.trans_spinner
                        .getSelectedItem().toString();

                Log.e("accno:", "" + accno);
                Log.e("name :", "" + tramnt);
                Log.e("position:", "" + position);
                Log.e("remark:", "" + remarks);
                Log.e("spinner:", "" + spinner);

                /****************** time and date **********************/
                // ----------Time----------
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                time = (c.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
                        + ":" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
                Log.e("Current Time", " " + time);

                // -----------Date---------
                Date now = new Date();
                Date alsoNow = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                currntdate = new SimpleDateFormat("M-d-yyyy").format(now);
                Log.e("Date ", " " + currntdate);

                status = new String("y");

                if (tramnt.equals("")) {

                    Toast.makeText(arg0.getContext(),
                            "enter Transaction amount", 5000).show();

                    Log.e("if cndition", " " + tramnt);
                } else if (spinner.equals("type")) {

                    Toast.makeText(arg0.getContext(),
                            "enter Transaction type", 5000).show();

                    Log.e("if cndition", " " + tramnt);
                }

                else {

                    if (remarks.equals("")) {

                        remarks = "null";
                    }

                    /************ declaration for dbcall *********************/

                    AccountDBAdapter db = new AccountDBAdapter(context);
                    NewTransactionSheet ts = new NewTransactionSheet();

                    try {
                        db.open();

                        String accid = db.getAccID(accno);
                        String Maxcramnt = db.getMaxCrAmnt(accno);

                        db.close();

                        Mamount = Double.parseDouble(Maxcramnt);
                        Bamount = Double.parseDouble(tramnt);
                        actualamnt = Mamount - Bamount;
                        balamount = "" + actualamnt;
                        db.open();

                        db.close();
                        /* Log.e("c value", " " +actualamnt); */
                        Log.e("tramnt", " " + tramnt);

                        Log.e("if cndition out", " " + tramnt);

                        db.open();
                        db.update_MaxCrAmnt(balamount, accid);
                        db.close();
                        actualamnt = 0;

                        db.open();
                        String userId = "" + 2;
                        db.insertTransactionTable(accid.toString(),
                                currntdate.toString(), spinner.toString(),
                                tramnt.toString(), userId.toString(),
                                time.toString(), remarks.toString(),
                                status.toString());

                        db.close();
                        holder.save.setText("SAVED");
                        holder.save.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                        // }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }

        });

    } catch (Exception c) {
        Log.e("adapter error", "" + c.getMessage());
    }
    return cv;

 }

}
```

Working on this for many days... need help.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use static final String[] data = new String[2];
set your values to this global array and retrieve from the same by index.

Comment: like transAmnt_edittxt.setText(data[0]);
remarks_edittxt.setText(data[1]);

Comment: there will be many rows.. so how to retrieve and set on particular position ?